# Get source file from EditorReference?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

In my eclipse plugin I have an EditorReference object for the CompilationUnitEditor where my source file is shown. Now, how can I get this source file from the CompilationUnitEditor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than a simple type cast to `IFileEditorInput` use the fact that `IEditorInput` extends `IAdapter`. Thus you get

```
IFile ifile = (IFile) myEditor.getEditorInput().getAdapter(IFile.class);
```

This works properly for `IFileEditorInput` but often also for other types of editor inputs that are based on other view of the storage system.

Answer (score 1):

Call the `getEditorInput()` on the editor to get back an `IEditorInput` object.  There are many kinds of possible inputs (source files) for an editor, but if it's a file then the value returned will also be an `IFileEditorInput` which has a method `getFile()` which returns a reference to the source file.

```
IFile ifile = ((IFileEditorInput) myEditor.getEditorInput()).getFile();
```

Comment: Not correct for any type of input that is not based on IFEI :-)

Comment: I know.  I said "but if it's a file..." per the question

Comment: I know... But the recommended way to access the file is to use adaption... This can work even for special GMF/XML types of editors which (almost) always have very special IEI...